# Best Book to Learn MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to read a book about MySQL database with emphasis on performance and optimization on Linux server. I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I actually answered a question like this on July 9, 2011

[Suggest a MySQL book for me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/suggest-a-mysql-book-for-me/3749#3749)

Let me expand on this answer:

When it comes to MySQL, the must have book is the [MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127). I have studied this book with a fine-toothed comb. At the time I bought the book, there was an errata page (list of typos in the book) provided my MySQL (the original MySQL, pre-Oracle, pre-Sun).

It forms a very good base for learning MySQL. However, to keep things in persepctive, let me tell you my experience using the book.

I actually purchased the book in September 2006 along with [MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892) and starting using it for everything tasks as a first year MySQL 5.0 DBA (I already had 2 years with MySQL 4.0 as Developer/DBA). After 10 months, I took the exams July 28, 2007 and August 11, 2007. I passed both exams on the first try because of two things: (1) Thorough study of the book and (2) practical experience.

Nothing can substitute for actual usage of MySQL. After proper due diligence and logging enough miles in MySQL, then this book will definitely help you get certified.

Other books will enlighten you further

- [MySQL Administrator's Guide and Language Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328704)
- [MySQL Database Design and Tuning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672327651)
- [High Performance MySQL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716)
- [Understanding MySQL Internals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009577)
- [MySQL High Availability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596807309)

BTW Yes, I do own all these books. I have read them and still use them !!!

Comment: Are the exams just MCQ questions?