# What are the concepts that need to be gone through for MySQL DBA?

Tags: mysql

I am a MySQL Developer, besides I am handling some DBA activities like 
backup, restore, mysql installation, etc at a top level.

Now I wanted to shift to DBA, So I wanted to know in depth, like which and concepts should be gone through as a DBA.

Also, what and all to be monitored on a daily basis.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Platform agnostic guidelines were discussed in http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/which-areas-of-a-dbas-knowledge-should-a-developer-delve-into/5844#5844.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **Storage Engine**

You should be very fluent with the use of two main storage engines: [MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/myisam/info) and [InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/innodb/info)

You must learn :

- how data and index pages are laid out
- [how table and indexes are cached](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)
- how table formats can make significant differences in reads and writes
- how table-level and row-level locking are handled
- [how queries that mix both storages engines affect performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475283/joining-innodb-tables-with-myisam-tables/5476284#5476284)
- how to backup data from each storages engine

### **MySQL Replication**

You should understand such things as

- What are the I/O and SQL Threads
- When log-slave-updates is necessary for a slave
- What allows you to write on a read-only slave
- When it's appropriate to use MyISAM/blackhole on a slave for tables that are innodb on the master
- How relay logs are populated
- How to recognize slave errors
- How to filter out/fileter in SQL for specific databases and tables
- Why run backups for slaves rather than masters

### **Troubleshooting and Tuning Queries**

- Learn how to run EXPLAIN on queries
- Learn how to create indexes to properly speed up queries
- Learn how to tune queries
- Learn how to activate the slow log
- Learn how to convert the slow log into MyISAM

### **INFORMATION_SCHEMA**

[You should learn how to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database for table info, row counts, last access info, and things like these](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336).

### **Third Party Tools**

The best tools that you should embrace are the following:

- [MAATKIT](http://www.maatkit.org/)
- [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/) (fork of MAATKIT also from Percona)
- [XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/)
- [MONyog / SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)

This is not a comprehensive list. However, it should be enough for anyone to be proficient as a Developer/DBA.

Here is Oracle's Certification Exam Descriptions that provide lists of skills within MySQL to have and know: [EXAM1](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_exam_id=1Z0_873) and [EXAM2](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=41&p_exam_id=1Z0_874)

[IMHO Here is a good set of MySQL Books to learn from](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/best-book-to-learn-mysql/4825#4825)