# How to maintain MySQL performance at high concurrency

Tags: mysql, performance, concurrency

The following has been observed using "mysqlslap".

```
mysqlslap -u root -p --create-schema=matrix --query=monthly_kpi.sql --iterations=1 --concurrency=1 --delimiter=";"
Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 2.735 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.735 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 2.735 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 1
        Average number of queries per client: 24

mysqlslap -u root -p --create-schema=matrix --query=monthly_kpi.sql --iterations=1 --concurrency=4 --delimiter=";"
Benchmark
        Average number of seconds to run all queries: 14.600 seconds
        Minimum number of seconds to run all queries: 14.600 seconds
        Maximum number of seconds to run all queries: 14.600 seconds
        Number of clients running queries: 4
        Average number of queries per client: 24
```

So with 4 concurrent users, the query time increases. How can we maintain similar query times even when there is a rise in concurrency ?

The my.conf file is as below:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=64M
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: You should add information about your server hardware/software configuration, too.

Comment: Can't seem to format it like we do in stackoverflow but here is the server configuration.                                  
1 CPUs
12 GB RAM
Intel Xeon
Ubuntu 12.04
Linux 3.2.0-29-generic x86_64

Comment: Default InnoDB settings? You won't get much from a servers configured like that. If you're using MyISAM - you shouldn't because of table level locks, they don't work well on high concurrent load. And the query cache should be disabled too. It is protected by a single mutex, all requests to it will be serialized, which is again not very good for high concurrency.

Comment: Few tables are MyISAM. Rest of the tables are InnoDB. So what do you recommend the ideal configuration should be to obtain max performance ?

Answer (score 7):

There is something missing from the my.cnf

[innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) are both 4 by default. You need to increase it to get InnoDB to use more CPU.

[innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency), which set to 0 (now defaulted to 0 since 5.5) lets InnoDB decide to create as many concurrency tickets as it needs. The default for [innodb_concurrency_tickets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets) is 500. Although you could change it, the default is usually the safest and you can focus on other tuning aspects of InnoDB I/O throughput.

I have discussed these CPU aspects of InnoDB before

- `Mar 16, 2012` : [Using multiple cores for single MySQL queries on Debian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15146/using-multiple-cores-for-single-mysql-queries-on-debian/15185#15185)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core/5670#5670)
- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)

CAVEAT : These aspects became available since MySQL 5.1.38's InnoDB Plugin was introduced.

You could also benefit from these other settings

```
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert and this is maybe a shot in the dark, but have you looked at any of the stuff about thread pools? It's interesting if nothing else :-) . I found [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/tag/thread-pool/), [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/26/why-do-we-care-about-performance-at-high-concurrency/) and [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/26/why-do-we-care-about-performance-at-high-concurrency/) (and links therefrom) gave me ideas. Only problem is that AFAICS, thread pooling is not available on MySQL GA, just Enterprise - only MariaDB and Percona Server (FLOSS). There was also [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/) about write intensive loads and using file system journalling to circumvent "InnoDB double write buffer" which might help - you don't mention your FS.